# Reminder Application

Tags: android

I am developing an application called reminder using android API. My Application reminds every event registered by user by SMS.
In Order to remind several users, all the reminding times should be raised at their respective time.
I am using `TimerTask` for that, but it is not accurate.
 Now i want to use `AlarmManger` for this, but in order to raise multiple reminders, all of them should be appended to object.

Can you please give me an solution for this. (No of registered reminders varies, i should remind every one depending up on the time they are given).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach appropriate extras to the `Intent` you use in the `PendingIntent` with `AlarmManager`, such as a `long[]` of your `_ID` values from your database for the rows relevant to this alarm.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, but here we have a scenario, we are taking time also as an input. so, for each row we will have different time. At that particular time we need to raise an alarm. sory, for not mentioning this in the question above.

Comment: @praddeepkalla: So? My answer still holds. You create one alarm for each time. In the extras for that alarm's `PendingIntent`, you attach whatever data you need to identify which events in your database the alarm is associated with.